# highcharts column drilldown along with a table

Tags: highcharts

say we are using this example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown, and that one chooses firstly chrome, and he is redirected to the next level. Then if he clicks on v17.0, if there was another level, we would be sent to the third level. But how one could implement this feature: when we click on version for example 17.0, we get a table with its child values, but without affecting at all the current 2nd level graph. So we have the graph with the versions, and whenever we click on each column, we get a table under the graph with the next level values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that drilldown series add click events for points:

```
drilldown: {
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], // some data e.g. Chrome
    point: {
      events: { 
          click: function() {
              // show your table after click on one of column
          }
      }
  }
  }]
}
```